# SQL min and max function not displaying proper results

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I am having a problem with using the MIN and MAX function in Microsoft SQL Server

The problem is regarding MIN and MAX functions displaying the results incorrectly.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(compression_ratio) AS minimum_cr,
    MAX(compression_ratio) AS maximum_cr
FROM dbo.C4m3practice
```

and it returns the MIN value 10 and MAX value 9.6, which doesn't make sense and is also both wrong.
I'll attach a picture below. What am I doing wrong?

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHABa.png)

Comment: Can you check running this query once;

`SELECT compression_ratio
FROM dbo.C4m3practice
WHERE ISNUMERIC(compression_ratio) = 0;` Whether there are any non-numeric values in your column

Comment: What datatype is compression_ratio?

Comment: The results are ok, what is wrong is the datatype of compression_ratio

Comment: Tushar Yes, everything is numeric. And I've just double checked with your query. Thanks for the reply. 
P.Salmon and nacho, everything is varchar, just checked it, every value is varchar, BUT before stumbling upon this problem i also checked the MIN and MAX for other parameters such as length and width and the result was correct. So its a bit confusing, as the data type is also consistent in the tested parameters, everything numeric and varchar (it was an imported file from CSV)
I am pretty new to SQL, so might be a basic fix, thanks you all for the answers.

Comment: You should change the datatype of that column pronto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like compression_ratio of type `varchar()`, you will need to convert your column to `float`

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CAST(compression_ratio as float)) AS minimum_cr,
    MAX(CAST(compression_ratio as float)) AS maximum_cr
FROM dbo.C4m3practice
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ratio was store in String related datatype. In ASCII, the '1' is before '9', that's why when SQL look at the first character and determine 10 is the min and 9.5 is the max.